# Problem when the Bot enters a voice channel

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a problem with my Bot. When I tell it to enter a voice channel, the Bot enters, but the program freezes, or rather, it doesn't go ahead in the function. I tried reinstalling PyNaCl and Discord.py[voice], but that didn't work. This is the program:

```
    @commands.command()
    async def join(self, ctx):

        if ctx.author.voice is None:
            return await ctx.send("You are not connected to a VC!")

        await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect() #it stops here
        msgg = await ctx.send('Connected!')
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await msgg.delete()
```

Also when I press the "Debug" button on the Discord voice channel, there is no Bot in the list of incoming data, although I see it in the channel:

[image]